# Background is not dimming in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-handler

I am using a fragment and there is a button as soon as I click on it the background will become dim and textView will be visible.The appearance of the dimming effect and text will take place at once.For some reason I don't get these result.

**Here is my code:-**

```
activate_wifi_button = (Button)wifi_and_hotspot.findViewById(R.id.Activate_wifi);

activate_wifi_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams=getActivity().getWindow()
                                .getAttributes();
            layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.7f;           
            getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
            getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text_animate_dots.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timer.cancel();
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(runnable);
            }
        }, 2000, 2000);
    }
});
```

I have used handler and runnable because I want to animate the textview for 2 sec but the animate part can come latter at first I need to do the above task.

Comment: `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` is flag used for dimming behind Window, and your Windows is probably fullscreen, so you cannot see it. It is used for CustomDialogs. You should probably modify background color of fragment itself.

Comment: so how I can make it work...

Answer (score 0):

For the desired output, you can take semi-transparent layout and textView in FrameLayout. In onclick method, set its visibility VISIBLE; and for better user experience, set Fade animation to textview.

Comment: will it be possible with relative layout

Comment: No, it would be possible by either Frame layout or constraint layout.